# How to grant a Service Principal access to AKS API when RBAC and AAD integration are activated?

Tags: active-directory, azure, kubernetes, rbac

I need to grant a process (build pipeline) RBAC access to AKS API for deployment purposes.
But the target AKS cluster has AAD integration active (as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration))

I was expecting to be able to access the AKS API's with a simple Service Principal, but I'm redirected to a devicelogin page:

```
$ az login --service-principal  --username [REDACTED]-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX --password [REDACTED]XXxxXXxxXXxxxXXXxxXXxxXXxx= --tenant [REDACTED]-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

$ az aks get-credentials -n oli-aksdemo01 -g oli-aksdemo01
Merged "oli-aksdemo01" as current context in /home/olivier/.kube/config

$ kubectl get nodes
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code C2NP77EGR to authenticate.
```

:-(

Is there a way to avoid the devicelogin page when authenticating a Service Principal on an AAD-integrated AKS cluster on Azure ?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike @Festus Fashola's answer, which works simply because it's using the `--admin` flag in the command which bypasses AAD verification (not what the OP was asking), the correct way of doing this now is using KubeLogin, which allows service principal non-interactive authentication: https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin#service-principal-login-flow-non-interactive

Usage example:

```
# login
az login --service-principal --username <sp_client_id> --password <password> --tenant <tenant>

# Get the admin credentials for the kubeconfig context
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource_group> --name <aks_name>

# convert your kubeconfig file
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig -l spn

# export variables with sp credentials
export AAD_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_ID=<sp_client_id>
export AAD_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=<sp_password>

# run any kubectl command, you shouldn't get the devicelogin verification message
kubectl get pods
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Make sure to install `kubelogin` with a `sudo az aks install-cli`, not via `snap` or anything.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone out there who still needs this.

I solved the same issue for my Jenkins pipeline. All you have to do is create a service principal with the cluster scope or subscription.

```sh
#login
az login --service-principal --username <app-key> --password <password> --tenant <tenant>

# Get the admin credentials for the kubeconfig context
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $resourcegroup --name $aksname --admin

#
kubectl get pods
```

you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR : It is not possible, yet.**
I asked the very same question to Azure support and here is their answer:

> When the AKS cluster integrated with AAD it will require redirecting
>   to the device login page when authenticating to access to the cluster.
>
> Access cluster with Azure AD -
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aad-integration#access-cluster-with-azure-ad
>
> Unfortunately this is currently by design and there is no other way to
>   avoid this process at the moment but we would love to hear your voice.
>
> Would you please provide your feedback through the links below so we
>   may plan in the future.
>
> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks